# I'm using a login script (PHP, MySQL) which uses sessions. I need to create a variable so i can use it in the other pages?

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication, account

The PHP script I have for the login.php which is the form is the code below.

```
<?php 
include 'dbc.php';

$user_email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

if ($_POST['Submit']=='Login')
{
$md5pass = md5($_POST['pwd']);
$sql = "SELECT id,user_email FROM users WHERE 
        user_email = '$user_email' AND 
        user_pwd = '$md5pass' AND user_activated='1'"; 

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ( $num != 0 ) { 

    // A matching row was found - the user is authenticated. 
   session_start(); 
   list($user_id,$user_email) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    // this sets variables in the session 
    $_SESSION['user']= $user_email;  


    if (isset($_GET['ret']) && !empty($_GET['ret']))
    {
    header("Location: $_GET[ret]");
    } else
    {
    header("Location: myaccount.php");
    }
    //echo "Logged in...";
    exit();
    } 

header("Location: login.php?msg=Invalid Login");
//echo "Error:";
exit();     
}

?>

<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<?php if (isset($_GET['msg'])) { echo "<div class=\"msg\"> $_GET[msg] </div>"; } ?>


<p>&nbsp;</p><table width="40%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0"     cellspacing="0">
  <tr> 
<td bgcolor="#d5e8f9" class="mnuheader" >
<div align="center"><font size="5"><strong>Login 
    Members</strong></font></div></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> 
<td bgcolor="#e5ecf9" class="mnubody"><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p align="center">Your Email 
      <input name="email" type="text" id="email">
    </p>
    <p align="center"> Password: 
      <input name="pwd" type="password" id="pwd">
    </p>
    <p align="center"> 
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
    </p>
    <p align="center"><a href="register.php">Register</a> | <a        href="forgot.php">Forgot</a></p>
  </form></td>
 </tr>
```

I want to create a session vairable like the $_SESSION['user']= $user_email; which i can use in other pages. The problem is i don't know how to do so and i want to select a different row from my database called points. So it will be something like 
    $sql = "SELECT id,user_email,points FROM users WHERE 
        user_email = '$user_email' AND 
        user_pwd = '$md5pass' AND user_activated='1'";

Like i say i want it to select the number of points so it can be used on all pages where the session has been start.

Here is an account page which echos the logged in user. But i want it to also echo the points row from my database.

```
  <?php
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
 {
 die ("Access Denied");
 }
 ?> 
 <h2>My Account </h2>
 <?php if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) { ?>
 <p>Logged as <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?> 

   <a href="settings.php">Settings</a> 
 <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> </p>
<?php } ?>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You code is vulnerable to [XSS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). Also please [don't use md5 to hash passwords](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: [md5 is insufficient protection for passwords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash)

Comment: Hmm, I would suggest to [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) about sessions ..

Answer (score 1):

put the session_start() start of the page

```
<?php
session_start();
```

your code follows this line the variables were working.

Answer (score 0):

You must place `session_start()` at the top of **any** pages you want to carry the session over to, so try that and see if that works :)

you should have the following to return a assoc array with the users details into a variable `$user`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email = '{$_SESSION['user']}'";
$res = mysqli_query($sql);
$user = mysqli_fetch_assco($res);
```

Also, `mysql_` is depreciated, so you should change all of your references of `mysql_` to `mysqli_`

Comment: SQL Injection possibility in there

Answer (score 0):

To creat a session variable,try doing the same as $_SESSION['user']= $user_email
So $_SESSION['WhateverYouWant']= $Anything

Comment: Or Maybe i miss understood what you want exactly :)